# A functor on the category of commutative rings, algebras or Banach algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-cohomology

**Edit:** According to the comments of  abx  and  Yemon Choi I revise the question as follows:

Let $G$ be  a  group and  $\mathcal{A_G}$ be the category of $G$-module commutative algebras, that is the category of  commutative  algebras which are acted  by  $G$ and the action preserves the  algebra structures.

We define the    functor $Nil_G:\mathcal{A_G}\to \mathcal{A_G} $ as follows:

$$Nil_G (A)=\{a\in A \mid g.a-a\; \text{is  a  nilpotent elementof $A$},\;\forall g \in G\} $$

This  functor can be defined on the  category of  commutative rings or  comuutative Banach algebras. For the later case  we consider $Nil_G(A):= \overline{Nil_G(A)}$.

A motivation for  construction of  such functor  comes from the classical "Group  Cohomology".  In the  group  Cohomology we  start with  the functor which maps  every $G$-module $M$  to $\{m| gm=m\}$ and the  corresponding derived functor  of this functor generats "group  cohomology". On the other hand $g.m=m$ is  equivalent to $g.m-m \in \{0\}$. Now  we replace $\{0\}$ by  the ideal of nilpotent elements or  the  torsion subgroup. in the group case.

> Is this  functor identical to a well known functor in the  corresponding categories?  Does it  posses some non trivial properties? In  particular, is  it always  a  full functor? If  not,  for  which kind  of  groups $G$  this functor  is  a  full functor?In this way, can we get a non trivial invariant in group theory?

**The  Group Cohomology Version**

If  we  consider the  same  construction  on the  category of  Abelian groups, we  obtain a  left exact  functor $Nil:\mathcal{Gr}_G \to \mathcal{Gr}$ with 
$$Nil_G (H)=\{a\in H \mid g.a-a\; \text{is  a  torsion  element of $H$},\;\forall g \in G\} $$

Here $\mathcal{Gr}_G$ and   $\mathcal{Gr}$ are category of $G$-modules and  abelian group, respectively.

> Does the corresponding derived  functor gives us a  kind of  useful cohomology theory? What would be the precise formulation of corresponding chain complex and coboundary maps?

Comment: Are you aware that your categories are not abelian?

Comment: You have to be careful with what you mean by "left exact" in categories like that of commutative Banach algebras. This is not just because the category is non-additive, but because there can be morphisms which are monic and epic yet are not isomorphisms

Comment: @abx  I am sorry that I did not pay attention to this fact.

Comment: And I thank you and @YemonChoi  for  your  comments.

Comment: About the last question: what is a "nilpotent element" in an abelian group?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly  Dear Prof. Moret-Bailly  I revise the question and replace "Nilpotent" by "torsion".